# Capistrano doesn't set RAILS_ENV for bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler, capistrano3

In my Gemfile I specify what branch to use on a git repository based on RAILS_ENV. However when Capistrano deploys, it runs the `bundle install` command - and since it's run through a shell, the proper environment (staging) isn't set. It defaults to development and gives me an error stating that there's a mismatch between Gemfile.lock and what is installed.

> You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing your
>   Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the updated
>   Gemfile.lock to version control.
>
> You have added to the Gemfile:
>       * source: git@bitbucket.org:MyRepository/manager-engine.git (at develop)
>
> You have deleted from the Gemfile:
>       * source: git@bitbucket.org:MyRepository/manager-engine.git (at master)
>
> You have changed in the Gemfile:
>        * manager from `git@bitbucket.org:MyRepository/manager-engine.git (at develop)` to `no specified source`

**Gemfile:**

```
RAILS_ENV = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development'
gem 'manager', git: "git@bitbucket.org:MyRepository/manager-engine.git", branch: "#{ [:production, :staging].include?(RAILS_ENV.to_sym) ? :master : :develop }"
```

i.e., use the 'develop' branch if the rails environment is anything other than 'production' or 'staging'.

**deploy/staging.rb:**

```
set :branch, :master
set :keep_releases, 2
set :stage, :staging
set :rails_env, 'staging'
set :bundle_without, [:development, :test]
set :deploy_to, '/home/useraccount/rails_deployments/staging.www'
server 'localhost', user: 'useraccount', roles: %w{web app db}
```

So to be the most concise:

In regular SSH terminal, to install the repository gem under the proper environment, I have to issue `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle install`. Otherwise, just running `bundle install` installs the repository from the develop branch. Since Capistrano just runs `bundle install` and doesn't include the `RAILS_ENV`, this problem is occurring. But doesn't Capistrano set :rails_env, or is that not a real system environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if there's no better way...

I ended up using a method illustrated somewhere else in SO and modified it for my needs.

Modify Gemfile to contain:

```
# Read environment from A) Explicit set through command, B) Existence of override file's contents or C) Default to development
RAILS_ENV = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || `cat .rails-env`.to_s.split.first || 'development'
```

If `.rails-env` contains nothing or doesn't exist, it defaults to development. Otherwise it takes the first word as the environment. To create the file from the command line, just type `echo "your-environment-name-here" > .rails-env`, assuming you're in the app's root directory.

You can also create the file upon every deploy with capistrano using the command above, or just create a symlink to the file and share it between deployments:

Deploy.rb:

```
set :linked_files, %w{ .rails-env }
```

So now the environment can be forced via a file in the root of your app called .rails-env. Explicit RAILS_ENV calls such as `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec ...` will still work as advertised.

Comment: The above RAILS_ENV= will throw an error on cat if .rails-env does not exist, another way is to use this at the top `RAILS_ENV = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || ( File.exist?('.rails-env') ? File.read('.rails-env') : 'development' )`

Comment: And if you want the line to work, then it should be like this:

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= ( File.exist?('.rails-env') ? File.read('.rails-env').to_s.split.first : 'development' )

Comment: Another comment to add, in your spec_helper.rb file, make sure the environment is explicitly set to 'test' as this overrides it!